# Is it correct to say that increasing the sampling frequency is same as compressing the duration of an audio signal in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, audio, audio-processing, music

I am trying to read and play with an audio signal in MATLAB. I have coded below

```
clear
[y,fs]=audioread('guitartune.wav');
sound(y,fs)
```

This audio clip'guitartune.wav' has approximately 15 sec duration when played noramlly with 'fs'

As frequency and time are in reciprocal relation , so when i update my last line of code and use 2*fs instead of fs, my audio clips speeds up and it finishes in almost 7 seconds

So what is happening above in reality? Increasing the sampling frequency is resulting in time compression of music/audio signal and now signal becomes x(2t) ?and similarly decreasing the sampling frequency will result in time expansion of audio signal and signal will become x(t/2)?

If my understanding and above working is correct,**how can we flip this music signal to get x(-t)** so the music file plays in reverse

Comment: Hmm... maybe this is wrong method to start learning DSP ... I suggest reading some related books https://dspguru.com/dsp/books/favorites/  (or watch YT videos https://tinyurl.com/m8ntj8n9 ).

Comment: Have you ever seen a [tape recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_recorder)? Increasing the tape speed is similar to increasing the sampling rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Increasing the sampling frequency is resulting in time compression of music/audio signal and now signal becomes x(2t) .... x(t/2) ?

Pretty much yes. Keep in mind that there are two sample rates in play: the recording sample rate and the playback sample rate. If you playback at $2f_s$ you change the playback sample rate only. The clip will play in half the time, but also the frequencies will all be doubled. So voice will sound like "Mickey Mouse".

> how can we flip this music signal to get x(-t)

```
sound(flip(y),fs); % or sound(y(end:-1:1),fs)
```

Comment: Here, in my code what is happening? Playback sample rate is changing or recording sample rate?? If it is change in playback sample rate, how can we change recording sample rate?

Comment: @jojo ... what you do changes the playback sample rate and you change the recording sample rate by up-sampling - https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/upsample.html and down-sampling https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/downsample.html